# Decryptor with keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am making a decipherer with a neural network with python3, this is what I have done so far:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import csv

LE = LabelEncoder()

dado = pd.read_csv('teste.csv', header=None)
print("codigo:",dado)
dado = LE.fit_transform(dado)

np.random.seed(2)

classification = 26

dataset = pd.read_csv('base.csv', header=None)

print("letras:",dataset[0])
print("\n")

print("codigo:",dataset[1])
print("\n")

dataset[0] = LE.fit_transform(dataset[0])
dataset[1] = LE.fit_transform(dataset[1])


print("letras:",dataset[0])
print("\n")
print("codigo:",dataset[1])


# Define dados de treinamento
X = dataset[0].values

#print("x: ",X)
# Define a saida padrao
Y = dataset[1].values
#print("\ny: ",Y)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.66, random_state=5)

#print("x_train:", x_train,"\n x_test:", x_test, "\ny_train:",y_train,"\ny_test:",y_test)
                                                

y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train-1, classification)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test-1, classification)

#print("\ny_train:",y_train,"\ny_test: ",y_test)

# A rede será uma MLP com duas entradas, uma camada intermediária com 3 neurônios e
# uma camada de saída com um neurônio.
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(26, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(classification, activation='softmax'))

# Mostra os parâmetros da RNA
#model.summary()

# 
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
print("OK")

# Executa o treinamento da MLP
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1, epochs=1000, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

# Executa a MLP após o treinamento
#print(model.predict(X))
#print(model.predict(dado))


prediction =model.predict(dado)

print("prediction: ",prediction)



#pred_name = dado[np.argmax(prediction)]
```

I'm using a base.csv to train:

```
 A,'@'
 B,'#'
 C,'$'
 D,'%'
 E,'&'
 F,'*'
 G,'1'
 H,'2'
 I,'3'
 J,'4'
 K,'5'
 L,'6'
 M,'7'
 N,'8'
 O,'9'
 P,'0'
 Q,a
 R,b
 S,c
 T,d
 U,e
 V,f
 X,g
 W,h
 Y,i
 Z,j
```

and I want to decrypt for example this message:

```
'@e*c$&7e3d96&1@7'
```

apparently the training is correct and I am receiving the value of predict (), i will put some of them:

```
 [1.67683919e-03 1.00730495e-05 3.00646033e-02 3.47359193e-04
  7.34448224e-10 2.07794699e-07 6.91458354e-07 9.16662440e-02
  1.12631470e-01 1.55544106e-03 1.33347882e-07 1.26970816e-08
  1.17909266e-07 2.84538746e-01 2.04548487e-04 4.61375207e-01
  4.84018710e-06 6.99752900e-06 1.09326131e-04 4.26771911e-03
  2.73230253e-03 1.45343272e-03 1.31152268e-03 5.98493521e-09
  3.70860286e-03 2.33352231e-03]
 [1.35914271e-03 6.58475028e-06 2.74186116e-02 2.63669877e-04
  3.23479521e-10 1.15685609e-07 4.04968659e-07 8.76267478e-02
  1.08614832e-01 1.25834497e-03 7.29217859e-08 6.29246166e-09
  6.41369695e-08 2.85867929e-01 1.51908389e-04 4.74235952e-01
  3.07537766e-06 4.51551887e-06 7.91385319e-05 3.59652541e-03
  2.26239045e-03 1.17159961e-03 1.05227530e-03 2.87827917e-09
  3.10653565e-03 1.91950181e-03]]
```

this is the input code of the encrypted file:

```
dado = pd.read_csv('teste.csv', header=None)
dado = LE.fit_transform(dado)
```

how do i show the predict() result back into characters to decipher the message?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just turn the data back into the original by passing through the network backward. You need to train another neural network to convert the data back into the original. Feed the second network your `y_train` and make it predict your `x_train` like so:

```
another_model.fit(y_train, x_train, ...)
```

The only other way of doing this would be to use a [GAN](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan) which TensorFlow provides a great tutorial on!